# How to retrieve objects out of Json in Azure Data Factory

Tags: arrays, json, azure-data-factory

I have a Json file that when run by Data Factory only contains one nested object "Properties" and it is fine but Value4 looks like another nested object and is being visible as one long string,  altough it contains multiple columns, same thing with Text1, is this a proper json format ? I cannot figure it out how to flatten this the only value that is detected by ADF is Properties as an object, Value4 and Text1 is not recognized by ADF as an object or array, just one long string of values

Any idea how to fix this problem or the Json is really badly created?

{"RoleInstance":"HIDDEN","City":"Boston","Country":"UnitedStates",]"ClientIP":"0.0.0.0","ClientStateOrProvince":"MA"
**"Properties"**:{"Value1":"Test","Value2":"12345","Value3":"User",
**"Value4":"**{"HostSpecType":"User","ListSpecType":"User","RoleID":"156","OwnerIDs":[159],"OwnerID":3,"ColumnsToLoad":["UsrID","SpecID","SpecName","SpecTyp","SpecOpt","ParentSpecID","ParentSpecTyp","InternalVersion","Email","Office","DispName","FirstName","LastName","Phone","OfcID","UserPrin","EmplID"]}",

"UserID":"498","MachineName":"QG6T",
**"Text1"**:"{"ID":"1596","Name":"LaunchSchedule","Type":"Initializa Mailbox Monitor","AppID":"1002"}",
"TaskID":"16415",
"JobID":"167"},

"ResourceGUID":"c94e4","SDKVersion":"dotnet:2-21496"}

Comment: what is your exxpected result?

Comment: Value4 should be listed as separate columns not one big string, same for Text1

Comment: the above JSON is your input?

Comment: yes unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your Json, I tried to reproduce the same  in my environment I got the same string values.

```
{  
"RoleInstance":"HIDDEN",  
"City":"Boston",  
"Country":"UnitedStates",  
"ClientIP":"0.0.0.0",  
"ClientStateOrProvince":"MA",  
"Properties":  
{  
"Value1":"Test",  
"Value2":"12345",  
"Value3":"User",  
"Value4":'{"HostSpecType":"User","ListSpecType":"User","RoleID":"156","OwnerIDs":[159],"OwnerID":3,"ColumnsToLoad":["UsrID","SpecID","SpecName","SpecTyp","SpecOpt","ParentSpecID","ParentSpecTyp","InternalVersion","Email","Office","DispName","FirstName","LastName","Phone","OfcID","UserPrin","EmplID"]}',  
"UserID":"498",  
"MachineName":"QG6T",  
"Text1":'{"ID":"1596","Name":"LaunchSchedule","Type":"Initializa Mailbox Monitor","AppID":"1002"}',  
"TaskID":"16415",  
"JobID":"167"  
},  
"ResourceGUID":"c94e4",  
"SDKVersion":"dotnet:2-21496"  
}
```

[image]

If you modified the Json like this, It will fix your problem:

```
{
    "RoleInstance":"HIDDEN",
    "City":"Boston",
    "Country":"UnitedStates",
    "ClientIP":"0.0.0.0",
    "ClientStateOrProvince":"MA",
    "Properties":
    {
        "Value1":"Test",
        "Value2":"12345",
        "Value3":"User",
        "Value4":
        {
            "HostSpecType":"User",
            "ListSpecType":"User",
            "RoleID":"156",
            "OwnerIDs":[159,144],
            "OwnerID":3,
            "ColumnsToLoad":
            [
                "UsrID","SpecID","SpecName","SpecTyp","SpecOpt","ParentSpecID","ParentSpecTyp","InternalVersion","Email","Office","DispName","FirstName","LastName","Phone","OfcID","UserPrin","EmplID"
            ]
        },
        "UserID":"498",
        "MachineName":"QG6T",
        "Text1":
        {
            "ID":"1596",
            "Name":"LaunchSchedule",
            "Type":"Initializa Mailbox Monitor",
            "AppID":"1002"
        }, 
        "TaskID":"16415",
        "JobID":"167"
    },
        "ResourceGUID":"c94e4",
        "SDKVersion":"dotnet:2-21496"
}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree, the json is poorly crated to say the least, thanks for input